# Select * from n tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, dynamic

Is there a way to write a query like:

```
select * from <some number of tables>
```

...where the number of tables is unknown? I would like to avoid using dynamic SQL. I would like to select all rows from all the tables that (the tables) have a specific prefix:

```
select * from t1
select * from t2
select * from t3
...
```

I don't know how many `t(n)` might there be (might be 1, might be 20, etc.) The `t` table column structures are not the same. Some of them have 2 columns, some of them 3 or 4.

It would not be hard using dynamic SQL, but I wanted to know if there is a way to do this using something like `sys.tables`.

**UPDATE**

Basic database design explained

N companies will register/log in to my application

Each company will set up ONE table with x columns

(x depends on the type of business the company is, can be different, for example think of two companies: one is a Carpenter and the other is a Newspaper)

Each company will fill his own table using an API built by me

What I do with the data:

I have a "processor", that will be SQL or C# or whatever.

If there is at least one row for one company, I will generate a record in a COMMON table.

So the final results will be all in one table.

Anybody from any of those N companies will log in and will see the COMMON table filtered for his own company.

Comment: If your tables are called `t(number here)`, you should really consider a different database design.

Comment: As is often the case, a description of the problem you are actually trying to solve would help us help you.

Comment: Instead of having each company set up their own table, you should just be placing all entries for the same type of company into the same table - add a column for `Company ID` (which you're going to want anyways, I hope).  Ideally, the `Common` table should already exist, with information common to all companies - only use the `type` tables for additional columns specific to that business type.

Comment: X-Zero, your idea sounds good, but it is not dynamic enough for me. I don't know how many company type will i have, that means that instead of N companies, I will have M types of companies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to list ALL tables you could try :

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'SELECT * FROM  ?'
```

you can programmability include/exclude table by doing something like:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'IF LEFT(''?'',9)=''[dbo].[xy'' BEGIN SELECT * FROM  ? END ELSE PRINT LEFT(''?'',9)'
```

Comment: +1 This is actually great. However OP should be aware that the result will bring **multiple** result sets, not one single result set. OP has to take that into consideration when programmatically accessing the result.

Comment: i like this, multiple result set is OK, this is what I had in mind, but because of performance, I thought I would search for a way to make it work without dynamic SQL

Comment: One word of warning about the accepted answer is that the sp_msforeachtable is undocumented and therefore theoretically Microsoft could alter it or remove it completely in a future SQL Server update with no warning.

Answer (score 10):

There would be no way to do that without Dynamic SQL. And having different table structures does not help that at all.

**Update**

There would be no easy way to return the desired output in one single result set (result set would have at least the same # of columns of the table with most columns and don't even get me started on data types compatibility).

However, you should check @KM.'s answer. That will bring **multiple** result sets.